# Is there an alternative to isolation level SERIALIZABLE?

Tags: mysql, isolation-level

I use MySQL 5.7 and want to run an export task on a products table. The process basically runs like this:

1. `SELECT * FROM products WHERE exported = 0`
2. Loop over the result set in my programm and write it to a file
3. `UPDATE products SET exported = 1 WHERE exported = 0`

So each product should only be exported once.

I found that I have to wrap the above in a transaction with isolation level `SERIALIZABLE` because I have another process that inserts records at the same time.

Otherwhise that other process could insert rows with `exported=0` while I'm in step 2) which would be missing in the file but get updated to `exported=1` in step 3).

Is this the best way to solve this kind of problems? Or are there any drawbacks or pitfalls I'm no aware of?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT * FROM products WHERE exported = 0 INTO OUTFILE "x/y/z" FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE products SET exported = 1 WHERE exported = 0;
COMMIT;
```

And I don't think it matters what the isolation mode is.

I am not sure of mixing `INTO OUTPUT` with `FOR UPDATE`; if it give you trouble, make it two `SELECTs`.

Note that this does obviate your program with the loop and write.  (And it will probably run faster.)

Another approach may be to ping-pong 2 tables.  One is receiving new rows; the other is being exported.  No need to have the `exported` flag.  More details:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table (especially the section on flip-flop staging).

Comment: Thanks. Is `FOR UPDATE` preferable to `SERIALIZABLE`? I thougth `FOR UPDATE` only locks the selected rows and protects them from modification. The docs don't mention that it will also prevent concurrent inserts of *new* rows. Even if it works in a test: I want to be confident about the solution and not rely on try & error (that's what brought me here ;) ). Regarding `INTO OUTFILE`: Yes, that would speed things up but it's not applicable in my case as I need to postprocess the data before writing. The example is really simplified.

Comment: @MichaelHärtl - I can't answer your question without devising a test.  Meanwhile, I added another approach.

Comment: Actually I ended up with a similar approach to the ping pong table: The export rows are inserted with `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` into a temporary table first and exported from there. Afterwards I update the `exported` flag (which we need) with an `INNER JOIN` on this temporary table and finally drop it. I just found the original setup to be an interesting use case to study the effect of isolation levels and locking and wanted a better understanding.